# How to updated dropdown selection to "selected" onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this React app, I have a dropdown menu to select between different options. When an option is clicked, it sets that option's value to the localStorage. However, once i move to a different page, the dropdown doesn't show the value that was selected, it defaults to the first option. I am guessing that I need to add functionality that when an option is selected, the item get's updated to have 'selected' in the element. How would i go about doing that?

This is the code:

```
<select onChange={(e) => window.localStorage.setItem('language', e.target.value)}>
  <option onClick={() => window.localStorage.setItem('language', 'en')}>en</option>
  <option onClick={() => window.localStorage.setItem('language', 'es')}>es</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `<select>` to a controlled component. On change, set state to the target's value as well as updating `localStorage`, and then render the `<select>` with a value of the state that was set:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(localStorage.getItem('language'));
```

```
<select
  value={value}
  onChange={(e) => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('language', e.target.value);
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }}
>
  <option>en</option>
  <option>es</option>
</select>
```

It may or may not be useful here, but a more general way to set `localStorage` when a particular state gets updated is to use `useEffect`, instead of putting the functionality next to each setter:

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('language', value);
  },
  [value]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom hook which controls the storage of the language with a `useState` hook.

```
const useLanguageStorage = () => {
  const [ language, setLanguage ] = useState(localStorage.getItem('language'))

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('language', language)
  }, [language])

  return [ language, setLanguage ]
}
```

Then use that hook in your component to set the new language whenever the `onChange` handler is called.

You can set the default selected value with the `value` property.

```
const DropDownComponent = () => {
  const [ language, setLanguage ] = useLanguageStorage()

  const handleChange = event => {
    setLanguage(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <select onChange={handleChange} value={language}>
      <option value={'en'}>en</option>
      <option value={'es'}>es</option>
    </select>
  )
}
```